# Given a cookie from a subdomain, can you write a javascript function that returns the hostname of the proxy server?

Tags: javascript, cookies, proxy, subdomain

Hello stackoverflowers,

I'm trying to make a variable that holds the value of the hostname of the proxy server, so I can dynamically construct a cookie name (which contains the hostname of the proxy as part of the string).  Do you know how I would do this?  I would imagine the hostname (and other info) of the proxy server is stored or is accessible somehow through the subdomain server.  Do you know of a javascript function that can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: "I would imagine the hostname (and other info) of the proxy server is stored or is accessible somehow through the subdomain server."  Why would you assume this? Is the proxy server under your control or does it belong to the user or his organisation?

Comment: The subdomain is a subdomain of the proxy server.  The proxy server is the main domain.  The subdomain is hosted by a third party.  The main domain is hosted by the organization I'm doing work for.

Comment: For example `subdomain.proxy.example.com` and `proxy.example.com`? Is it restricted to 1 level subdomains? If so don't you just chop off the first component to get the hostname of the proxy server?

Comment: The domains are like subdomain.example.com and proxy.example.com, so you can't just chop off like that.

Comment: So chop off one element and add the word "proxy". It's your proxy so you know what it is called. What's the problem? (It might help if you gave concrete examples including **whether you are trying to set the cookie from the browser, the server, or the proxy**). Also is it a standard web proxy or is it a custom application doing some proxying.

Comment: it's client-side javascript that will set a cookie with the name being : string + proxy server name (x) + string.  I need to get the hostname from where we have proxied from.  It's a standard web proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of possibilities spring to mind.

1. If it is dynamically generated content, just write the proxy name into an element in the web page and retrieve it from there. On the server side, you can look up the client IP address - which will be the address of the proxy - in a list you maintain, to find out the proxy name.
2. If it is static content, use an AJAX method from the browser to query the server for the proxy name, which the server can provide in the same way as method 1.
3. Just give the proxies the same name so the cookie can have the same name every time.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but none of these solutions are feasible for me.  Rethinking my problem, is there a way to use javascript to read the host name from browser’s address bar?

Comment: `document.location.host` does that.

Comment: Thank you! I actually found that there is a global variable that already contains the host URL.  So I parsed that in order to make my dynamically constructed cookie name.  I'm about to start testing!  Appreciate your input!